# Allure report not working on Jenkins pipeline matrix

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, allure

Please refer the below Jenkins Pipeline

```
stages {
    stage("Build Matrix Project") {
        matrix {
            axes {
                axis {
                    name "CITY_NAME"
                    values "CITY_01", "CITY_02"
                }
            }
            stages {
                stage("Build and Run Tests") {
                    steps {
                        ....
                    }
                }
                
                stage("Generate Reports") { 
                    steps {
                        allure commandline: "Allure 2.18.1", includeProperties: false, jdk: "", results: [[path: "target/allure-results"]], reportBuildPolicy: "ALWAYS"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The allure report gets generated successfully for both CITY_01 and CITY_02.
But the allure results of CITY_02 over-writes CITY_01.

Please let me know, how to fix this?

Comment: Your job can only publish one allure report per execution (when using the allure plugin). What about combining the two reports (test executions) in to a single report and publishing it?

Comment: The problem with this is that all the test cases will be listed twice for CITY_01 and CITY_02

Comment: Indeed, but they can be separated by executions. And when you will run more configurations in the matrix, it will be easier to see them all in one report then have multiple separated ones.

Comment: Can you please help with the steps to achieve this? "What about combining the two reports (test executions) into a single report and publishing it?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is run all the matrix builds in parallel as you do now, then  instead of publishing the report stash it for later use and save its name in a global list.
After the parallel execution is over (or in the post section) unstash all the reports and publish them altogether as a single report (in a separate none matrix stage) that will contain all the tests from all matrix configurations.

Something like:

```groovy
REPORTS =[]
stages {
    stage("Build Matrix Project") {
        matrix {
            axes {
                axis {
                    name "CITY_NAME"
                    values "CITY_01", "CITY_02"
                }
            }
            stages {
                stage("Build and Run Tests for ${CITY_NAME}") {
                    steps {
                        // build code & run tests

                        // stash the results
                        stash name: CITY_NAME, includes: "target/allure-results/*.*"
                        REPORTS.add("${CITY_NAME}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Generate Allure Report") {
        steps {
            REPORTS.each {
                dir(it) {
                    unstash name: it
                }
            }
            def resultList = REPORTS.collect { [path:"${it}/target/allure-results"] }
            allure commandline: "Allure 2.18.1", includeProperties: false, results: resultList, reportBuildPolicy: "ALWAYS"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the following Exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.results expects class ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.config.ResultsConfig but received class java.util.ArrayList
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {commandline=Allure 2.18.1, includeProperties=false, jdk=jdk_17.0.3_7, reportBuildPolicy=ALWAYS, results=[[{path=CITY_01/target/allure-results}, {path=CITY_02/target/allure-results}]]} for ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher`

Comment: I have updated the answer, in the allure command it should be `results: resultList`, and not `results: [resultList]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Noam Helmer. You are a savior.